# Contact Form 7 Plugin

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, contacts

In WordPress my Contact Form 7 is giving me an error message. (There was an error trying to send your message try again later).  Can someone tell me what the problem is.  I have never had this problem before.  This is the response after I click the send button.   Thanks

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the response or the error message that you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You need external SMTP on you Wordpress, because `phpmail()` function is disabled on your server. You should use an plugin to configure SMTP on your Wordpress for example this one: [Easy WP SMTP](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) plugin. Important - you need a email from which emails from Wordpress will be sent to configure Easy WP SMTP plugin.